# Toggle a column visibility in Angular 8 + Nativescript

Tags: nativescript-angular, android-gridlayout

I have a view displaying a table with two columns. I have to hide/ display a column based on a toggle button click. When I use visibility property and change the visibility of the second column, I see that the first column doesnt occupy the entire screen .

```
 <RadListView row=" 2" [items]="itemList">

            <ng-template let-item="item" >
                <GridLayout  columns="*,*" class=""    >
                    <Label column="0" [text]="item.labelid + '.' + item.text[0]" textwrap="true"
                           class="p-15 border-table text_font"></Label>
                    <Label   column="1" [id]="item.labelid" [text]="item.labelid + '.' + item.text[1]" textwrap="true"
                           class="p-15 border-table text_font"></Label>
                </GridLayout>


            </ng-template>

        </RadListView>
```

Component.ts

```
onCompareTap(args) {
        this.isCompare = !this.isCompare
        this.itemList.forEach((item) => {
            var crLabel:Label = <Label>this.page.getViewById(item.labelid);
            crLabel.visibility= this.isCompare ? 'visible' : 'collapse';
        })


    }
```

I want to show the single column occupying the full screen when the user toggles the view.  The trick lies at tacking the  `GridLayout  columns="*,*"`  where I am specifying the number of columns which I couldn't change at run time. Thoughts please.